# Mac OS X Finder filter image by orientation

Tags: finder, graphics

How can I filter images by orientation in Finder to show only portrait/vertical images or only landscape/horizontal images?

Answer (score 12):

From https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3481136:

1. Search for images by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

   [image: search for an image]
2. Add a search attribute

   [image: add search attribute]
3. Pick the "Orientation" attribute

   [image: look for "orientation search attribute]
4. Set "equals" to

   - 0 if you want landscape/horizontal,
   - 1 if you want portrait/vertical

   [image: landscape vs portrait]

Comment: That is awesome.

Comment: OS X metadata is indeed awesomely powerful, as well as extensible when needed.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X El Capitan, to bring up the search screen I use the key combination <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>, instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>.